# Why does Facebook show restriction message for canvas url when logged out?

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-apps

If I go to the canvas url of an app when logged out of Facebook, it shows a scary message "Use of app "App Title" has been restricted".

Example: https://apps.facebook.com/postergifts/

I do not have any restrictions on the app and have no warnings in the developer console. When logged in to Facebook, everything works fine.

This doesn't happen for https://apps.facebook.com/farmville-two/ which shows a login form.

What could it be about my apps that is causing the message about restriction to be displayed?

In the advanced settings, it has this:

```
Country Restrictions: Blank
Let users without a location see my app: Checked
Age Restrictions: Anyone 13+ 
Content Restrictions: alcohol not checked
Social Discovery: Enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that "allow users without a country" need to be UNCHECKED.

Bug submitted:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/467722223296519?browse=search_517692e7066001974683076